# How to prevent imageView of UIButton from taking up entire UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

I am trying to make an `UIButton` programmatically with an icon and a title (as default, icon should be on the left next to the title). However, the icon is quite big in size so when I use `myButton.setImage()` the icon stretches and takes up the entire button, the title also disappears.

I also tried to set `imageEdgeInsets` but it does not make the title appear. 
So is there any way to make the icon smaller (maybe `.scaleToFit`) and the title appear again?
If not, how small the icon (relatively to the button) should I export?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this extension to `UIImage`:

```
extension UIImage {
    func resizeToBoundingSquare(_ boundingSquareSideLength : CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        let imgScale = self.size.width > self.size.height ? boundingSquareSideLength / self.size.width : boundingSquareSideLength / self.size.height
        let newWidth = self.size.width * imgScale
        let newHeight = self.size.height * imgScale
        let newSize = CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize)
        self.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
        let resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return resizedImage!
    }
}
```

Say you have a 1024x1024 icon that you wish to resize as 40x40. Just do this:

```
var myIcon = UIImage(named: image)
myIcon = myIcon.resizeToBoundingSquare(40)
```