# CIContext Memory Leak issue in Xcode 9 in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode9

When using `CIContext.createCGImgage`, I get memory leak issue on Xcode 9.when take image from camera it took more memory and then the app get crash

Here is my Code,

```
let ciContext = CIContext()
func callFillter() {        
    let coreImage = CIImage(image: self.appDelegate.selectPic)
    for i in 0..<CIFilterNames.count {
        itemCount = i
        if self.originalImage.image != nil{
             autoreleasepool() {
            print("originalimage\(self.originalImage)")
            self.imageToFilter.image = self.originalImage.image!               
            print("originalImage\(self.imageToFilter.image!)")
            print("coreImage\(coreImage)")
            let filter = CIFilter(name: "\(CIFilterNames[i])" )
            filter!.setDefaults()
            filter!.setValue(coreImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
            let filteredImageData = filter!.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage
            if let output = filter?.outputImage {
                ciContext.clearCaches()
                autoreleasepool(){
                let filteredImageRef = ciContext.createCGImage_(image: output, fromRect: filteredImageData.extent)
                var filterButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
                filterButton.frame = CGRect(x: self.xCoord, y: self.yCoord, width: self.buttonWidth, height: self.buttonHeight)
                filterButton.tag = self.itemCount
                filterButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = true
                filterButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.filterButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
                filterButton.layer.cornerRadius = 6                            
                filterButton.clipsToBounds = true                            
                let imageForButton = UIImage(cgImage: filteredImageRef)
                filterButton.setBackgroundImage(imageForButton, for: UIControlState())
                self.xCoord +=  self.buttonWidth + self.gapBetweenButtons
                self.filtersScrollView.addSubview(filterButton)

            }
        }
    }
    print("itemCount \(itemCount)")
    filtersScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: (buttonWidth + 5) * CGFloat(itemCount + 1), height: yCoord)

}
```

and the function called from

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
```

}

That take huge amount of memory and the app get crash.

Comment: The very first thing I see - and your code posted doesn't really help - is you are creating a `CIContext` *every single time* you call this `callFillter` function. That is a very "expensive" thing to be doing. Create a single `CIContext` and share it. (This may not be your issue - you haven't posted what calls this function.)

Comment: This is not a leak, you are just using too much memory. If you want to make duplicates of a photo and keep them in memory, you need to scale them down to the resolution you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting as an answer because I've looked at your code and "get" what you are trying to do.

A few things wrong with your code - but the *primary* thing is you are creating a `CIContext` every time you call this function. Move that context out of your function - make it more global - and you'll see not just better memory usage but better performance.

Second, it look like you are creating a scrollview of various filters applied to a single image. Based on that, why not get rid of `autoreleasepool()` and `ciContext.clearCaches()`? These don't really accomplish anything.

Since Swift (by default) passes read-only parameters into a function, why not add the `CIImage` (or else the `UIImage`) as a parameter to make your code more easy to use and debug?

Finally, you are looping at `for i in 0..<CIFilterNames.count` and doing *a lot* inside that loop. Pull that code out. Make it a function. It might help figure out the memory leak.

**Again, my bet it creating a `CIContext` for *every single iteration* in that loop is the cause. Move that out and code to use a single context - not just for every iteration in that loop, but every call to `callFillter()`.

Comment: Hi thank you for replying.And then already I declare the ciContext in out side the callfilter() function.then it will gives me same error.

Comment: First, I did my best to correct your code markdown. Let me know if I didn't do it properly. A few additional thoughts - you state the the error happens when you take a camera image. How about a static image that is smaller? (It may help to debug the issue.) If a smaller image size works, take a look at an extension I proposed here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47980838/how-to-prevent-imageview-of-uibutton-from-taking-up-entire-uibutton/47980891#47980891) and see if this helps you with a large camera image. Finally, how large if the `CIFiletNames` array?